# How to set MongoDB automatically assign ID to each sub-document?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
public class SubClass {
    public bool isValid {
    get;
    set;
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public List < SubClass > SubClasses {
    get;
    set;
    }
}

MainClass m = new MainClass() {
    Name = "Mohsen", SubClasses = new List < SubClass > (new SubClass[] {
    new SubClass() {
        IsValid = true
    }
    })
};
MongoMainClassCollection.Save < MainClass > (m);
```

The problem is that all SubClass ID's have a default value of zero.
I want MongoDB assign a unique ID for any SubClass whenever I save a MainClass.

Is there a way to configure MongoDB to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB won't do this automatically for you. MongoDB doesn't add ID's to subdocuments. Best bet would be to add something in your Subclass constructor to automatically populate the ID for you.

```
public class SubDocument {
    //if using objectId as ID
    public ObjectId Id = { get; set;}

    public SubDocument(){
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you also provide code so I can choose as answer

Comment: The code is irrelevant you could implement it several ways depending on how you wanted to set the Id and what type you wanted the Id to be set to.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to save object in it's constructor so the ID is assigned. However this caused a lot of side effects like saving empty objects. Any code that help me to assign ID automatically is completely relevant!

Comment: You're not saving the sub document in the constructor you just need to assign your ID a value.